# AWS SAM - Esbuild Failed: cannot find esbuild

Tags: typescript, aws-sam, esbuild

I'm trying out AWS SAM with nodeJS and Typescript using 'sam init', but when I want to build the example hello-world-typescript application using 'sam build', I get the following message:

```
Building codeuri: C:\RF\GitHub\rf-09-06\hello-world runtime: nodejs14.x metadata: {'BuildMethod': 'esbuild', 'BuildProperties': {'Minify': True, 'Target': 'es2020', 'Sourcemap': True, 'EntryPoints': ['app.ts']}} architecture: x86_64 functions: ['HelloWorldFunction']
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:CopySource
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:NpmInstall
Running NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle

Build Failed
Error: NodejsNpmEsbuildBuilder:EsbuildBundle - Esbuild Failed: cannot find esbuild
```

Any idea how to resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using @vercel/ncc for a less disruptive build process. You can keep the `node_modules` and other files like `package.json` as is in their original location, instead of moving stuff around.

Answer (score 17):

It can be solved in either of the 2 ways:

1. Install esbuild globally using `npm install -g esbuild`
2. As mentioned in the [AWS SAM github issues](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/4183#issuecomment-1234862956), **move esbuild to non-dev dependency** (`npm install esbuild`) -  Since esbuild will bundle your code, it won't be packaged in your Lambda.

PS: latest version of hello-world-typescript has this already corrected as mentioned in point 2.

Comment: This should be the preferred answer!

Comment: This actually solved the problem for me. [AWS CodeBuild]

Comment: Neither solution works. Upon trying to install esbuild globally, the `install.js` file under `esbuild` can't be found within the global node_modules folder. Using NVM results in same, just within the nvm  global node_modules folder. Trying to install locally results in same error, within the local node_modules folder.

Comment: I was exhausted on trying the 1st option, thanks for the 2nd, it worked

Answer (score 6):

I had to install esbuild globally to get this working
`npm install -g esbuild`

Comment: BEWARE: This fixes the problem but it might introduce inconsistencies among versions of esbuild. Please, refer the @user11666461 for better explanation

Answer (score 1):

install esbuild, you can use npm for that

```
npm install esbuild
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It has been installed, but still no luck. What else it can be?

Answer (score 0):

You can install esbuild as development dependency and run sam build in package manager (ex: pnpm) scope

example:

`pnpm sam build`

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering this issue as well. I put `sam build` as an npm script so that it looks at your project's `node_modules`.

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "sam build"
  }
}
```

This way you don't have to install `esbuild` globally. Then just `npm run build` or `yarn build`